# Yii2 save multiple data records in once

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

How can I save multiple data records in once for example,

```
$model->title = "Negativ Balance";
$model->settingsName = "negativeBalance";
$model->settingsValue = "0";
$model->save();

$model->title = "Warnung Balance";
$model->settingsName = "warningBalance";
$model->settingsValue = "2";
$model->save();
```

If I do these code, only the last records are saving, how can I save in once all these data? Thanks!

Comment: you're working over the same record. Create different records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  must create a new model and then assign the values

```
$model = new YourModel();

$model->title = "Negativ Balance";
$model->settingsName = "negativeBalance";
$model->settingsValue = "0";
$model->save();

$model = new YourModel();

$model->title = "Warnung Balance";
$model->settingsName = "warningBalance";
$model->settingsValue = "2";
$model->save();
```

but if you need  several insert you clould also take a look at  `batchInsert()` method of `yii\db\Command` see this for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert%28%29-detail

Comment: this is wrong way

Comment: @Kshitiz   . why ??'

Comment: there is a thing call batch insert for multiple insertion. calling same class multiple time is not required. if you have 1000 record then how slow is your system going to be? php is 10 times slower than any other language. and if you have 1000 user inserting 1000 record then what? you can also read mysql transaction.

Comment: The answer  is stricly related to sample provided by the OP and for this my answer  is correct  .. the   "thing call batch insert "  is based  on  `batchInsert()` method of `yii\db\Command` see this for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert%28%29-detail ...amyway . based on your suggestion i have added  some info in my answer  for this tecnique too  . .. thanks  ..